# How to add color to transparent area of font awesome icons

Tags: html, css, colors, icons, font-awesome

I want to change the transparent middle portion of `fa-youtube-play` icon to red. I try this code:

```css
.fa {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

But sing this code will overlaps the icon. How do I make color to the inner transparent are only?

Comment: Maybe just give a line-height? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8quddpp1/1/)

Comment: @Huelfe elegant

Comment: Could you put the background color on the div that contains the icon instead of the icon itself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

universal means no. I'm afraid you'll have to work with each icon individually.

```css
.fa {
  background-image: radial-gradient(at center, red 40%, transparent 40%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using psuedo character i.e. `:after`. This might help:
    https://jsfiddle.net/kr8axdc3/

Answer (score 1):

In CSS use the `clip` property like so `.fa { clip: rect(0px,0px,0px,0px); }`. Set to whatever values are appropriate. I believe this property only applies to images, however.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see there are many ways to do it. The easiest way to fix this is to add `line-height`.

```css
div .fa {
  background-color:red;
  line-height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one,

```
.fa{
       background-color:red;
       line-height:25px;
        width:40px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could even do that using pseudo selector `:before` as below, bit lengthy styling but adds background to that transparent area.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```